# react-navigation - display 'are you sure' dialog before navigating back

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am building an app in react native with the use of react-navigation. On one screen I need to display a simple dialog to make sure user really wants to exit that screen.

I've tried to add `BackHandler` listener but that does not apply when the user clicks on the back arrow in the header. Is there any way, how I can prevent transition back before user click on the alert button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

implement "headerLeft" of Screen Navigation Options, like

```
headerLeft=()=>{
     return <Button onPress={}>
}
```

then you can do anything you want in onPress callback

Comment: Did not think of that. Thanks :)

Comment: Great thing is, that I can use `HeaderBackButton` so it will look exactly the same as default...

Comment: How can I show a warning box on HeaderBackButton?